# htaccess 301 redirect subdomain to different domain

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect

I want to redirect my subdomain to different subdomain on a different server.

```
   blog.mydomainname.com  ->  mydomainname.otherdomain.com
```

I tried this on .htaccess unsuccessfully:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^blog.mydomainname.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://mydomainname.nationbuilder.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Where is the problem?

Comment: You can do it configuring vhost, i guess, but doing by .htaccess is a patch.

Comment: That rule should work fine if .htaccess is enabled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick for you, just remove the '^'

```
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^blog.mydomainname.com$
  RewriteRule (.*)$ https://mydomainname.nationbuilder.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: This worked for me when several other SO threads had solutions that did not.